# Using pagination with filtered entries

Tags: conditionals, pagination, solspace-user

I am filtering a list of entries using an {if…} conditional, but the exp:entries tag outputs the count for the total number of entries before the conditional is applied. And as I am using pagination I end up with a wrong number of pages. Does anyone know if there is an easy way to fix this?

My code looks something like this:

```
   {exp:user:users group_id="9|10|11" orderby="lastname" sort="asc" limit="300" paginate="bottom" }

    {if location_area =="{segment_3}"}
     {title}
    {/if}

{user_paginate}
Page {user_current_page} of {user_total_pages} &nbsp; {user_pagination_links}
{/user_paginate}

{/exp:user:users}
```

As you can see I'm using the Solspace User addon.

Thanks for any help.

Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to change your conditional to be a [`search` parameter filter](http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/users/#search).

```
{exp:user:users ... search:location_area="{segment_3}"
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please be sure to mark this answer as the solution.